# Why is the map: $GL_n(K)\times GL_n(K) \to GL_n(K)$ regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field and $GL_n(K)$ the set of all invertible $n$ by $n$ matrices over $K$. Let $m: GL_n(K)\times GL_n(K) \to GL_n(K)$ be the usual multiplication of matrices. Why the map $m$ is regular? Thank you very much.

Comment: The maps are just polynomials in the entries? In particular, if you identify $\text{GL}_n(K)$ as the set of pairs $(A,B)$ in $K^{n^2}$ such that $AB=1$ (where you use regular matrix multiplication), then this is obvious.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, thank you very much. But what is the product of $(A, B)$ and $(C, D)$ in $K^{n^2}$?

Comment: I am not saying you should. If $R$ is an algebraic ring, then you show that $R^\times$ is a variety by identifying it with the set $(x,y)$ in $R^2$ with $xy=1$. For example, $k^\times$ is an affine $k$-variety, isomorphic to the set $xy=1$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First forget $GL_n(K)$ and work in $M_n(K)$. The multiplication map 
$$ M_n(K)\times M_n(K)\to M_n(K)$$ 
is polynomial in the entries:
$$((x_{ij})_{ij}, (y_{kl})_{kl})\mapsto (\sum_{r} x_{ir}y_{rl})_{il}, $$ 
so it is a regular map. When you restrict to $GL_n(K)$, you get a regular map 
$$ GL_n(K)\times GL_n(K)\to M_n(K).$$ 
As the multiplication lands in $GL_n(K)$, you get the statement you want to prove.

Comment: thank you very much. But the multiplication is the multiplication of matrices. Why it is a polynomial?

Comment: @IJR: a matrix $(x_{ij})_{ij}$ is viewed as element of $K^{n^2}$.